# Mine BitCoins on a Mac?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, mining-software

Ok, so I can mine BitCoins on my Mac... using my Windows Partition.

Like a lot of people I hate Windows.

I'd use Linux first (I have a WUBi partition), but I'd like a BitCoin miner for Mac that does **not use OpenCL**!

I'm using

- a Mid 2012 MacBook Pro
- with integrated Graphics,
- 2.5GHz processor Core i5
- 4GB RAM.

My laptop does not support OpenCL. I know of MacMiner, but I believe that needs OpenCL. Using my CPU to mine (on Windows) I get 1.7MHz, but on the GPU (on Windows) I get 4.7 and sometimes 5MHz.

I'm getting an iMac this Christmas, so maybe it'll be a little better for this.

So yeah, how can I start mining BitCoins on my Mac? Any software?

Comment: Keep your profitability in mind. You aren't likely to be profitable mining on such a device.

Comment: You can use your Mac to mine with ASIC devices. The BitMinter client works fine for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hardware is useless for mining. You'd spend more money on power than you could ever make back mining on a rig that isn't built for mining.

Comment: So would you recommend waiting for my iMac? It'll be the cheapest 21" model. I've heard people saying they get 100GHz on it, and the ButterFly Labs machine can get about 2.5Billion GHz. That's about 10 minutes for 250 BTC, if I remember right!

Comment: You won't be happy mining bitcoins on the same computer that you use for work, because it will slow the computer down significantly. Instead, buy an asic, or build a cheap computer with some video cards off ebay. http://thegenesisblock.com/asicminer-lowers-usb-miner-price-to-0-89-bitcoins/

Comment: I completely agree that the mining is impractical and will result in charges, not profits.  However, unless I am mistaken, the question was not "Is this a good set-up or choice?" but rather "how does he or she accomplish the objective of mining with the above hardware?"  Personally, I think there is a lot to be learned about mining bitcoin by configuring the impractical options like OpenCL, GPU, CPU, set generate true, delving into the .conf file, etc., and then should one's interest be piqued, going further later.  Thus, I recommend the @John answer below as a great way of learning.

Comment: @oemb1905 When reading the question, I didn't get the sense that it was exploratory or experimental.

Comment: You might be right ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use your CPU to mine in the main bfgminer window that opens when MacMiner starts, or you can use the view menu to get to CPU Miner window, if you're interested in mining LTC or some other scrypt currency.

http://macminer.fabulouspanda.com/

as an aside, the CPU is actually detected as an OpenCL device, so it may be appropriate to change the question to 'How can I CPU Mine BTC on a Mac?'

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to spend some money to be profitable. Your graphics card like mine is unable to support 1GH/s so I'd recommend buy an ASIC miner and use a supported system with drivers (like Parallels or your Linux partition) alternatively you could contract your mining. http://coinminer.biz/ is the best deal I've found for one year contracts.